# AsyncTask e Adapter para ListView em conflito

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter, asynctask

Estou criando um app chat usando socket e após desenvolver todo o layout decidi entrar na parte de conexão... o problema é que quando recebo mensagens o app fecha e apresenta alguns erros... passei no debug e me diz que tanto meu adapter quanto meu listview estão null. Sou novo em android e java.

segue um pedaço do erro (linha 224 é onde adapterMessage.add(message)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.stevenilson.appchat, PID: 26141
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void adapters.MessageAdapter.add(objetos.Message)' on a null object reference
    at com.stevenilson.appchat.TelaDrawer.receive(TelaDrawer.java:224)
    at AsyncTask.TaskConnect.doInBackground(TaskConnect.java:80)
    at AsyncTask.TaskConnect.doInBackground(TaskConnect.java:26)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Caso precisar ver mais do projeto tenho ele no GitHub: https://github.com/LucasGitDev/AppChat

agradeço desde já a quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, seu erro não parece ser nenhum tipo de conflito entre o AsyncTask e o adapter não. Pelo que vi o erro aconteceu em background sim, mas porque você tentou acessar um objeto nulo, no caso, o MessageAdapter está nulo.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void adapters.MessageAdapter.add(objetos.Message)' on a null object reference

Confira se inicializou ele direito, talvez esse seja o problema.